# Custom ListView is repeating one row

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have created a **custom ListView** with one **ImageView** and one **TextView**. I also created **custom adapter from ArrayAdapter** and I´m using **array of classes (MonsterLink[])** to get all informations to the adapter. But the ListView is still repeating one row. I tried to find the solution here (and I did, with the setTag, getTag) but it didn´t help and I dont really understand it. This is my first app.

CreateView where I call the adapter:
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Load view
        this.MyView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container,false);

```
    //Change the category label
    SetCategoryLabel();

    //Load DB;
    LoadDatabase();

    //Create list for MonsterList
    MonsterLink[] MonsterLinkList = LoadMonsterLinkList();
    MonsterAdapter monsteradapter = new MonsterAdapter(this.getContext(), MonsterLinkList);
    ListView MonsterList = (ListView) MyView.findViewById(R.id.list_Monsters);
    MonsterList.setAdapter(monsteradapter);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return this.MyView; //inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
}
```

My adapter:

```
 public class MonsterAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MonsterLink> {

public MonsterAdapter(Context context, MonsterLink[] MonsterNames) {
    super(context, R.layout.monster_row, MonsterNames);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder mHolder;

    // Get the data item for this position
    MonsterLink monster = getItem(position);
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.monster_row,parent,false);
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();

        /**TextView MonsterName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_MonsterName);
        ImageView MonsterPic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_MonsterPic);**/

        mHolder.mName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_MonsterName);
        mHolder.mPic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_MonsterPic);

        convertView.setTag(mHolder);


    }else {
        mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }



    mHolder.mName.setText(monster.getName());

    return convertView;

}

private class ViewHolder{
    private TextView mName;
    private ImageView mPic;
}
```

}

As I said this is my 1st app on Android and I dont really understand how the ViewHolder in the adapter works.

**EDIT - New adapter**
My adapter now looks like this:

```
public class MonsterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return monsterList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

ArrayList<MonsterLink> monsterList;
Context context;

public MonsterAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MonsterLink> MonsterNames) {
    this.monsterList = MonsterNames;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
    MonsterLink monster = monsterList.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.monster_row,parent,false);

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_MonsterName);
    ImageView pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_MonsterPic);
    name.setText(monster.getName());
    return convertView;

}
```

}

I can´t see any rows now

Answer (score 1):

Try extending your adapter from the class

> BaseAdapter

And also, try making a local MonsterLink array list to contain the list in the adapter
Guessing you're not going to show tons of data, it's ok if you don't recycle your views, because if thats what you want, I highly recommend you RecyclerView.

Try the following (not tested):

```
    public class MonsterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        ArrayList<MonsterLink> monsterList;
        Context context;
        public MonsterAdapter(Context context, MonsterLink[] MonsterNames) {
            this.monsterList = MonsterNames;
            this.context = context;
        }

       @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get the data item for this position
            MonsterLink monster = monsterList.get(position);
           LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.monster_row,parent,false);

        /**TextView MonsterName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_MonsterName);
        ImageView MonsterPic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_MonsterPic);**/

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_MonsterName);
        ImageView pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_MonsterPic);
        //name.setText('bla bla')
        //name.setText(monster.getName())
        return convertView;

       }


       @Override
       public int getCount() {
          return monsterList.size();
       }
```

Comment: What do you mean? You can see that Im sending MonsterLink[] MonsterNames as a parameter to the adapter. This array is already filled. Inside MonsterLink[] I have two objects (two names), but ListView is showing the same name on every line.

Comment: Works? @Somachr

Comment: No, I can´t get through `super(context);` It says that I cannot use context here.

Comment: Excuse me, remove the super. It doesn't need to call the parent constructor

Comment: Edited question
Now I don´t see any ListView (no rows). I have changed the MonsterLink[] to ArrayList<MonsterLink> and checked if it is filled.

Comment: I forgot, if you don't override the function getCount, it automatically returns 0, so I've added a function called getCount in the adapter, check the edit @Somachr

Comment: Now I have the same problem as before. Two lines with the same name. [pic](http://imgur.com/a/bYK0X)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122596/discussion-between-firecat-and-somachr).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Firecat I (we) have located that the error is not in the adapter but when the list of items is created. The list is then sent to the Adapter.

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            List.add(new MonsterLink(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2)));
        }
        cursor.close();
```

This will normaly work fine but my object MonsterLink contained this:

```
public class MonsterLink {

private Static String Name;
private Static String PicPath;
private Static String MonsterID;
```

**I shouldn´t have use static variables!**
Everytime I have created new MonsterLink I changed these three variables for every object in the array.